# How would I include toBase64Image class using the fxcosta library for Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am (quite obviously) very new to development. I am trying to get my output chart to save as an image, but after searching I cannot see the toBase64Image class included in the library (really hope I am explaining this well). If someone understood what I am trying to achieve, is there a way to manually input the toBase64Image class? The library I am using is https://github.com/fxcosta/laravel-chartjs and doing this using the Laravel framework.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing `toBase64Image` is, is a wrapper around the default `canvas.toDataUrl` so it only renames it. This means you can just get the canvas ID in your application and call the `toDataUrl` on it

Documentation of `toDataUrl`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Chart.js implementation: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/1df4883aff050e9e320f9327be96e228fcc588cc/src/core/core.controller.js#L885